What is up with the beat in Bach's Goldberg Variations Aria?
The time signature of Bach's Goldberg Variations Aria is 3/4. However, when you hear interpreters like Glenn Gould playing it, it sounds almost like rubato. There are pauses that aren't in the sheet music; some parts are played slower or faster than the overall tempo. It is beautiful, of course, but it also sound like a mess in terms of tempo.
I get the concept of performance, I get that it isn't a static, robotic thing. And I get that music isn't expected to sound mechanical and some liberties are even expected from players (like, there is more room for rubato in Chopin than in Mozart, for instance). However, unlike some of Chopin's works, for instance, where I can empirically understand how slowing down or speeding up some parts make the music more emotional by emphasizing musical ideas, with Bach's Aria, I feel, it's a different thing entirely: I get the impression that there isn't an overall beat behind the music: try to count in 3/4 and you'll lose the beat very fast; try to use the metronome rigidly and it is a completely different music from the one I hear performers play.
I don't know if I'm being able to express myself correctly. I'm a self taught pianist and I'm sure there are more eloquent and technical ways to say what I'm trying to say.
But it is almost as if, for some parts, the beat is at the interpreter's choice. I hope I was able to convey what I mean, because I would really like to figure out a way to count the beat correctly.

At Eastman I heard a lecture by Nelita True called "Please Don't Play in Time."

Rubato isn't a time signature.  You can play any piece of music rubato (though it may not be stylistic).

I'm not going to attempt an answer right now because it's such a broad topic, but we should note that expectations of fluctuation depend on genre and context. In some, absolute regularity is expected: Most modern pop, Sousa marches, works of Steve Reich, etc. In others, a metronomic performance would be seen as a mistake. And within those genres there are differences: a baroque minuet is expected to keep moving fairly steadily, while a baroque "prelude" can be quasi-improvisatory and quite fluid.

One other thing to consider: A time signature can be present even on music that intends to be fluid. There is such a thing as music with no meter or beat, but it's pretty rare. More common is music that intentionally "warps" or manipulates a conceptual beat, and for that to work, there has to be a conceptual "default" that is being manipulated.

“It is beautiful, of course, but it also sound like a mess in terms of tempo.”  This and some comments in your second paragraph sounds like you are somewhat frustrated by this lack of metronomic tempo. You say you get it isn’t a static robotic thing so why not embrace it? There is no need to try and force a steady 3 count on this. In this day and age of click tracks and quantizing this piece is incredibly refreshing.
The key to feeling this piece is in the left hand/lower register. It plays mostly quarter notes ascending in pitch with some measures that are partially eighth or 16th notes. The notes in the lower register also outline the harmony. If you focus on that you can clearly hear the “3” pulse of the piece. I suggest not counting but just feeling the quarters and eighths in the low register as your guide.
I listened only to Gould, both the 1955 and 1981 versions. He is playing in a fluid way but within that fluidity there is a steadiness. There are no long fermatas or big ritards typical of true rubato. Another interesting point is that the 1955 version starts faster than the 1981 version but both versions gravitate in the opposite direction, the 1955 slows and the 1981 gets faster. That indicates to me that he was ok with taking it somewhere different from where it started.
I found this online and it confirms the predominant pulse in the bass clef, which Bach actually wrote as two separate voices:


Also the many ornaments in the right hand tend to be performed fairly freely with respect to meter and rhythm, and Gould is no exception.

"You say you get it isn’t a static robotic thing so why not embrace it?". That's the point: what parameters to use? Should I just play what i feel?

@Eulavo There are many necessary skills required to play music such as playing in tempo, understanding rhythm, melody and harmony, etc. Once you have a basic grasp of these things you can choose to play in a very technically accurate way or take liberties and be expressive, or as you say, play what you feel. There are no parameters for this, it is up to you to choose how to play as a creative musician. Maybe you would prefer to play this piece in a different way than Gould. That is valid as well.

@Eulavo “Should I just play what I feel?” — In essence, yes. However, in my experience (as a learner and teacher, although not of the piano), most people benefit from using a very steady beat when learning a piece like this (with the aid of a metronome if needed), before moving on to playing ”what they feel”.

I had to work through this same problem.
My early training was very metronome-based, and even small ventures away from strict meter would throw me completely and make the performance sound like a complete mess to my ears.
The solution was learning to hear more flexibly, and this took more time, training, and experience. There's no specific way to do this other than to listen to and play a lot of music. However, a few things that were helpful to me:

Listen to singers. They will often be very loose with rhythm, but by focusing on the phrasing and lyrics, it can help make sense of of what they're doing.
Schubert's Op. 142, no. 2. I played this piece and would speed up the B section a bit. But then I heard a recording (I no longer recall who, but Richter is below), and actually broke out laughing when the middle section came — it was so fast! (compared to how I played it). That really opened my eyes in terms of how much room there was for variation within a piece. I can't say what piece(s) might have that effect for you, but I hope you'll find it/them.
Practice "weirdly". If only to entertain myself, it was fun when practicing some piece to see how far I could take things: what happens if I play "this part" really fast? or slow? or staccato? or ...?
Play beginner music. This might have been the most important for me, but it had to come after that others. Get "book 1" of any method series (I used The Music Tree) and try playing those songs expressively. If you can get expression out of a song comprising only two different pitches, both quarter notes, then you can get music out of anything. But this exercise, likely more than anything else, taught me how much room for nuance there can be.





In my opinion you are perfectly right about the time signature. I already did a 4/4 version of the first part of this aria based on Gleen Gould interpretation. And the strangest thing, if you do a sonata-like left hand, it will really feel like a Mozart sonata.
I think I know why Gleen Gould did such dramatic change in the tempo at the beginning of the Aria. I think he started giving a emphasis on the ornaments. He liked the change, then he changed some of the duration of the notes. Then he liked even more, then he changed the tempo of the music to give this dreaming feeling.
Also, the music itself doesn't have a steady note feeling. I mean, there are 2th, 4th, 8th, 16th and 32th notes very close of each other. It start with very long notes, then there are faster notes, until it gets a 16th steady feel at the end of it. I think it is harder to count the beat. This gives a strange feeling to the music, like someone wakening.
